# How to get missing Redirects functionality not available in upgraded 9.3 installation working

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

According to [Sitecore Docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/map-a-url-redirect.html) v9.3 should have the ability to do redirects ootb.
[image: SS1]
However, it is not available and doesn't exist in the content tree anywhere.

We started out with v9, I believe. (before I came onboard) Then, we were 'upgraded' by a vendor team but from what I gathered it was mostly changing config version strings, mostly. Guessing new functionality requires more additions of dlls/configs, etc?

My questions are:

- Can I add the functionality myself as-it-is?
- Is it not OOTB and must be installed?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is part of the Sitecore Experience Accelerator; as such is it not necessarily included in a default 9.3 installation.

Sitecore Experience Accellerator, also known as Sitecore SXA or just SXA is a paid-for add on product to the base Sitecore XM or XP product offerings. As such  you would need a license for it, and then it could be installed onto your solution.

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask around to see if that is included.